# How to get model values passed to a base template in different apps?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a base.html template in my application called index. I has a model  this template receive some data from my model called footer

```
class footer(models.Model):
credits = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
phone = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='')
email = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='')
address = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='')
country_city = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default='')
```

In the same app, into the folder templates I have the template base.html which takes some values from my model footer

```
<li>
 <a class="foot-in" href="mailto:{{footer.email}}">{{ footer.email }}</a>
</li>
<li>
 <p>{{ footer.phone }}</p>
</li>
```

When I run the url in the app called index, everything goes well, but when I use the same template in another app, the url doesn't show the information from the model.

How can I make to make that the base.html template works well into the different apps of my website?

I hope I had been clear in my problem. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a [Custom Context Processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) for this. For example:

```
# context processor
# assuming it is in path /project/app/context_processors.py

def get_footer_context(request):
    footer = Footer.objects.last()
    return {
        'footer': footer
    }
```

Then update the `context_processors` in **`settings.py`**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # rest of the context_processors
                'app.context_processors.get_footer_context', # <-- Add your context processor
            ],
        },
    },
]
```